# ScrollChange event equivalent on iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to hide a button when the user is scrolling through the page so a specific area of the page is not blocked by the button, after the user finish scrolling I will show the button again after a delay of `1000-1500ms`. My idea so far is that I will subscribe to the scroll changing event, hide the button, wait for specific delay, show the button again. I managed to implement it for `Android` platform using effect like this:

```
public class AndroidScrollingEffect : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlatformEffect
{
    private bool _isAttached;
    public static void Initialize() { }
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        if (!_isAttached)
        {
            Control.ScrollChange += Control_ScrollChange;
            _isAttached = true;
        }
    }

    private void Control_ScrollChange(object sender, global::Android.Views.View.ScrollChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var command = ScrollingEffect.GetCommand(Element);
        command?.Execute(null);
    }

    protected override void OnDetached()
    {
        if (_isAttached)
        {
            Control.ScrollChange -= Control_ScrollChange;
            _isAttached = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The implementation is working just fine, for `android` platform. Now, I want to do the same thing for `iOS`. So, is there an equivalent event for `ScrollChange` on `iOS`?

**P.S.** I want to use effect so I don't write code in the code behind of the page and still able to bind to a specific command in the view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forms `ScrollView` is rendered as `UIScrollView` on iOS. So you can try the code below to construct your custom effect:

```
public class iOSScrollingEffect : PlatformEffect
{

    UIScrollView nativeControl;
    private bool _isAttached;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        nativeControl = Control as UIScrollView;
        if (nativeControl != null && !_isAttached)
        {
            nativeControl.Scrolled += NativeControl_Scrolled;
            _isAttached = true;
        }
    }

    private void NativeControl_Scrolled(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }
    protected override void OnDetached()
    {
        if (_isAttached)
        {
            nativeControl.Scrolled -= NativeControl_Scrolled;
            _isAttached = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I'm having `InvalidOperationException` `Event registration is overwriting existing delegate`

Comment: I manged to solve it by creating a custom delegate. Is there a better approach?

Comment: This exception occurs because you both register the delegate and `Scrolled` event. Try to remove the delegate, you can use this event without exceptions.

Comment: No I didn't. I just used the code you demonstrated in your answer. After I get the exception I searched for the cause. It turns out that `iOS` internally uses an `internal/system` delegate for each `Control` for such events, so when you register your event you overwrite the internal delegate. As you can see from [this question](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/40416/event-registration-is-overwriting-existing-delegate), after that I created the custom delegate to solve the problem I will post it as an answer so you tell me if it's a bad approach. Have you tested your answer?

Comment: Of cause `Scrolled` can be used if you didn't do any configuration in your Forms. Try to create a blank scroll to test that. Also you can try my sample [here](https://github.com/landl0526/ScrollViewDemo).

Comment: I will chose your answer for now as I can't test the sample right now because I'm in the office, I will test it tonight. Thanks so much for your responsiveness.

Comment: Glad if it helped you. Moreover Delegate is not a bad approach, it's just another way to do that. Both the two methods can fit your request, but they can't work together.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173070/discussion-between-mahmoud-and-land-lu-msft).